# Can't overwrite partition in Hive table

Tags: sql, hive, database-partitioning

I'm trying to overwrite a certain partition of a table. My query is pretty large, but I managed to find a minimal code that reproduces the error. When I try to run this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE sbx.calls_out PARTITION (date_call) 
SELECT
    z.corp,
    z.time_call,
    z.comp,
    z.serv
    z.date_call
FROM (
    SELECT
        'a' as corp,
        1 as time_call,
        'b' as comp,
        '20190625' as date_call,
        'c' as serv
) AS z;
```

This returns the following error:

```
Failed to recognize predicate '.'. Failed rule: 'regularBody' in statement
```

However, if I run the exact same code but using another table, it works alright. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: There isn't the partition to overwrite only the column name. Try with date_call = xxxx. From documentation: INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tablename1 [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...) [IF NOT EXISTS]] select_statement1 FROM from_statement;

Comment: @FrancescoSerra I didn't understand your suggestion. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: try this:

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE sbx.calls_out PARTITION (date_call = '20190625') 
SELECT
    corp,
    time_call,
    comp,
    serv
FROM (
    SELECT
        'a' as corp,
        1 as time_call,
        'b' as comp,
        'c' as serv
) AS z;

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **`,`** before **`z.date_call`** column, add `,` and run the statement again.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE sbx.calls_out PARTITION (date_call) 
SELECT
    z.corp,
    z.time_call,
    z.comp,
    z.serv,
    z.date_call
FROM (
    SELECT
        'a' as corp,
        1 as time_call,
        'b' as comp,
        '20190625' as date_call,
        'c' as serv
) AS z;
```